# Possible to get all posts with my shortcode?

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting

So here's what I'm trying to do.  I'm building a plugin for a business directory.  Each business is assigned to a category.  There are two views, listing and detail.  To give the user as much flexibility as possible, I have created a shortcode where they can pass in the category and that will display the listview.  This works great.  They can create a page, called "Fishing" with a permalink of "/fly-fishing" and the content is

```
   Here's some title information about our fishing.  Thanks yadda yadda.
   [business-directory category=fishing]
```

Notice that the category and the permalink are different.  Again, to show the flexibility I'm trying to achieve.

In my listings, I would like a permalink to each business that uses the permalink of the category page that they select.  So one might be /fly-fishing/abc-fishing.  When that permalink is visited, I need my plugin to know that the category is actually fishing and the business is abc-fishing.

I'm having trouble with creating the add_rewrite_rule such that it knows what page to pass back to.  My thought was to query each page, look for my shortcode, and then add the rewrite_rules accordingly.  This means I will have to do this on every page creating/update.

Is there a better way?